# Serving external webpages through a single website

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, proxy

So I'm trying to make a webpage to show a few different webpages (google, facebook, reddit) on a single website. I want it to be similar to iframe functionality, except these websites all block iframe through x-frame-options, so I can't serve it normally.

I've seen websites that can serve other websites like this, however. Web proxies such as [HMA](https://www.hidemyass.com/proxy) (try typing in www.facebook.com) serve up websites like this fine, but when I try to even curl facebook, it doesn't work.

I'm using node.js serverside if that matters.

Comment: I think that you must query those website through their API to retrieve data that you can then display on your own website.

Comment: @Kryptos yes, but if they don't have an API, or it doesn't include the data that I want, then I'm out of luck.